# Finding PID parameters .. How?

Tags: control, control-system, pid-controller

[image]

As in the picture , how can I determine ki , kp , kd 
I tried (using provided data) by finding ζ and ωn 
But I end up with third order transfer function could not subsitute my results to find PID parameters (ki kp kd ) values

Comment: Hi and welcome.  Please edit the post so the graphic appears correctly oriented.

Comment: Look up "dominant pole" in your book.  If you have one pole or pole pair that's much slower than the rest, that pole or pole pair tends to dominate.  *From the math provided* you've got the freedom to select all three poles.  Choose the real pole to be enough higher than the resonant pair to be considered "dominant" by your book, and proceed.

Comment: BTW: your provided transfer function doesn't look right for a PID in the forward path.  You may want to put your block diagram into a separate question along with your derivation; ask if you got it right.

Comment: Hi in fact this is answer sheet in page 5 they used "standered transfer function .. Why they equate alpha to 10 .. https://www.studocu.com/en-us/document/university-of-the-west-of-england/control/mandatory-assignments/control-report-part-2-cwk/1193038/view

Answer (score 1):

Well, we know that a second order system can be written in the following form:

$$\mathcal{H}\left(\text{s}\right):=\frac{\text{Y}\left(\text{s}\right)}{\text{X}\left(\text{s}\right)}=\frac{1}{\frac{1}{\omega_0^2}\cdot\text{s}^2+\frac{2\beta}{\omega_0}\cdot\text{s}+1}\tag1$$

When there is overshoot we know that:

- Overshoot (in \$\text{%}\$):
  $$\text{D}=100\cdot\exp\left(-\pi\cdot\frac{\beta}{\sqrt{1-\beta^2}}\right)\tag2$$
- Rise time:
  $$\text{t}_\text{p}=\frac{\pi}{\omega}\tag3$$

And we have overshoot so we know the relation between \$\omega\$, \$\omega_0\$ and \$\beta\$:

$$\omega=\omega_0\cdot\sqrt{1-\beta^2}\tag4$$

So, we get (using your biggest values):

- $$10=100\cdot\exp\left(-\pi\cdot\frac{\beta}{\sqrt{1-\beta^2}}\right)\space\Longleftrightarrow\space\beta=\frac{\ln\left(10\right)}{\sqrt{\pi^2+\ln^2\left(10\right)}}\tag5$$
- $$1=\frac{\pi}{\omega}\space\Longleftrightarrow\space\omega=\pi\tag6$$
- $$\omega=\omega_0\cdot\sqrt{1-\beta^2}\space\Longleftrightarrow\space\omega_0=\sqrt{\pi^2+\ln^2\left(10\right)}\tag7$$

So:

$$\mathcal{H}\left(\text{s}\right):=\frac{\text{Y}\left(\text{s}\right)}{\text{X}\left(\text{s}\right)}=\frac{1}{\frac{1}{\pi^2+\ln^2\left(10\right)}\cdot\text{s}^2+\frac{\ln\left(100\right)}{\pi^2+\ln^2\left(10\right)}\cdot\text{s}+1}\tag8$$

Comment: Here in page 5 https://www.studocu.com/en-us/document/university-of-the-west-of-england/control/mandatory-assignments/control-report-part-2-cwk/1193038/view they used " standered form " i dont understood why they equate alpha (α) to 10 ..